# Por qué no puedo generar rooms con licode?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nodejs

Buen día, estoy trabajando con el webRTC Licode, estoy tratando de generar distintas Rooms para que pueda acomodar a distintos usuarios en diferentes Rooms creadas. Sin embargo, no me está generando los cuartos, cada usuario que genero lo ingresa en un mismo cuarto que se crea por default.

Este es el código que utilizo para generar los cuartos:

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Licode Basic Example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="erizo.js"></script>
    <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
      </head>

      <body>    
        <button id="recordButton" onclick="startRecording()" disabled>Grabar Conversación</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    /* globals Erizo */
    'use strict';
    var serverUrl = '/';
    var localStream, room, recording, recordingId;

    function getParameterByName(name) {
      name = name.replace(/[\[]/, '\\\[').replace(/[\]]/, '\\\]');
      var regex = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)'),
          results = regex.exec(location.search);
      return results == null ? '' : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }


    ////////////////////////// Funcion toggleSlideShowMode() //////////////////////////
    var slideShowMode = false;

    function toggleSlideShowMode() {  // jshint ignore:line
      var streams = room.remoteStreams;
      var cb = function (evt){
          console.log('SlideShowMode changed', evt);
      };
      slideShowMode = !slideShowMode;
      for (var index in streams) {
        var stream = streams[index];
        if (localStream.getID() !== stream.getID()) {
          console.log('Updating config');
          stream.updateConfiguration({slideShowMode: slideShowMode}, cb);
        }//fin if
      }//fin for
    }//fin toggleSlideShowMode()
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    ////////////////// Esto es lo que se va a cargar de inicio ////////////////////////
    window.onload = function () {
      recording = false;
      var screen = getParameterByName('screen');
      var roomName = getParameterByName('room') || 'basicExampleRoom';//linea original
    //  var roomName = getParameterByName('room') || 'p2p';
//      var roomName = getParameterByName('room') || 'myFirstRoom';

      var roomType = getParameterByName('type') || 'erizo';//linea original
    //  var roomType = getParameterByName('type') || 'p2p';
      var onlySubscribe = getParameterByName('onlySubscribe');
      console.log('Selected Room', roomName, 'of type', roomType);
      var config = {audio: true,
                    video: true,
                    data: true,
                    screen: screen,
                    videoSize: [640, 480, 640, 480],
                    videoFrameRate: [10, 20]};
      // If we want screen sharing we have to put our Chrome extension id.
      // The default one only works in our Lynckia test servers.
      // If we are not using chrome, the creation of the stream will fail regardless.

      if (screen){
        //config.extensionId = 'okeephmleflklcdebijnponpabbmmgeo';
      }

      localStream = Erizo.Stream(config);//Inicializacion del stream con los valores de config
    /////////////////////////////fUNCION PARA CREAR EL TOKEN//////////////////////////////
      var createToken = function(roomData, callback) {

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = serverUrl + 'createToken/';

        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (req.readyState === 4) {
        callback(req.responseText);

          }
        };

        req.open('POST', url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.send(JSON.stringify(roomData));
      };//Fin var createToken = function(roomData, callback)
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      //var roomData  = {username: 'user', role: 'presenter', room: roomName, type: roomType};
      var roomData  = {username: 'DrSimon', role: 'presenter', room: roomName, type: roomType};

      createToken(roomData, function (response) {//El token de usuario necesita un nombre y un rol
        var token = response;//aSIGNACION A LA VARIABLE TOKEN EL TOKEN GENERADO POR EL SERVIDOR, este token siempre es distinto y permite agregar un nuevo participante a un room
        console.log("token generado: "+token+"\n");
    alert("token generado: "+token+"\n");
        room = Erizo.Room({token: token});//Aqui se creará el objeto room pasando el token que estos usuarios han recibido previamente de su servicio. Este token tiene que recuperarse utilizando la API del servidor , ya que es un token de acceso de usuario.

        var subscribeToStreams = function (streams) {
          var cb = function (evt){
              console.log('Bandwidth Alert', evt.msg, evt.bandwidth);
          };
          for (var index in streams) {
            var stream = streams[index];
            if (localStream.getID() !== stream.getID()) {
              room.subscribe(stream, {slideShowMode: slideShowMode, metadata: {type: 'subscriber'}});
              stream.addEventListener('bandwidth-alert', cb);
            }
          }//Fin for
        };//FIn var subscribeToStreams

        room.addEventListener('room-connected', function (roomEvent) {
          var options = {metadata: {type: 'publisher'}};
          var enableSimulcast = getParameterByName('simulcast');
          if (enableSimulcast) options.simulcast = {numSpatialLayers: 2};

          if (!onlySubscribe) room.publish(localStream, options);
          subscribeToStreams(roomEvent.streams);
        });//FIn de room.addEventListener

        room.addEventListener('stream-subscribed', function(streamEvent) {
          var stream = streamEvent.stream;
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.setAttribute('style', 'width: 320px; height: 240px;float:left;');
          div.setAttribute('id', 'test' + stream.getID());

          document.getElementById('videoContainer').appendChild(div);
          stream.show('test' + stream.getID());
          console.log('test del ID->'+stream.getID+"FIN");
        });//Fin de room.addEventListener

        room.addEventListener('stream-added', function (streamEvent) {
          var streams = [];
          streams.push(streamEvent.stream);
          subscribeToStreams(streams);
          document.getElementById('recordButton').disabled = false;
        });//Fin de room.addEventListener

        room.addEventListener('stream-removed', function (streamEvent) {
          // Remove stream from DOM
          var stream = streamEvent.stream;
          if (stream.elementID !== undefined) {
            var element = document.getElementById(stream.elementID);
            document.getElementById('videoContainer').removeChild(element);
          }//Fin if
        });//Fin de room.addEventListener

        room.addEventListener('stream-failed', function (){
            console.log('Stream Failed, act accordingly');
        });//Fin de room.addEventListener

        if (onlySubscribe) {
          room.connect();
        } else {
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.setAttribute('style', 'width: 320px; height: 240px; float:left');
          div.setAttribute('id', 'myVideo');
          document.getElementById('videoContainer').appendChild(div);

          localStream.addEventListener('access-accepted', function () {//Detector de eventos para saber cuando el usuario permite el acceso a camara y microfono
            room.connect();
            localStream.show('myVideo');
          });//Fin localStream.addEventListener
          localStream.init();//Inicializamosel stream
        }//FIn else 
      });
    };
        </script>

        <div id="videoContainer"></div>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Este es el codigo del servidor:

```
/*global require, __dirname, console*/
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    errorhandler = require('errorhandler'),
    morgan = require('morgan'),
    N = require('./nuve'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    https = require('https'),
    config = require('./../../licode_config');
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('../../cert/vid_botonmedico_com.key').toString(),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../../cert/vid_botonmedico_com.crt').toString()
};
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (config.erizoController.sslCaCerts) {
    options.ca = [];
    for (var ca in config.erizoController.sslCaCerts) {
        options.ca.push(fs.readFileSync(config.erizoController.sslCaCerts[ca]).toString());
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var app = express();

// app.configure ya no existe
app.use(errorhandler({
    dumpExceptions: true,
    showStack: true
}));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//app.set('views', __dirname + '/../views/');
//disable layout
//app.set("view options", {layout: false});

//Inicializamos el servidor con un servicio que va a estar corriendo 
N.API.init(config.nuve.superserviceID, config.nuve.superserviceKey, 'http://localhost:3000/');

var defaultRoom;
const defaultRoomName = 'basicExampleRoom';//Linea original

/////////////////////////// Funcion getOrCreateRoom ///////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Aqui se pueden obtener o crear rooms ////////////////////////////
var getOrCreateRoom = function (name, type = 'erizo', callback = function(){}) {//linea original

    if (name === defaultRoomName && defaultRoom) {
        callback(defaultRoom);
        return;
    }

    N.API.getRooms(function (roomlist){
        var theRoom = '';
        var rooms = JSON.parse(roomlist);
        for (var room of rooms) {
            if (room.name === name &&
                room.data &&
                room.data.basicExampleRoom){

                theRoom = room._id;
                callback(theRoom);
                return;
            }//fin if
        }//fin for

        let extra = {data: {basicExampleRoom: true}};
        if (type === 'p2p') extra.p2p = true;

        N.API.createRoom(name, function (roomID) {
            theRoom = roomID._id;
            callback(theRoom);
        console.log('P2P room created with id: ', roomID._id);
        }, function(){}, extra);//Fin N.API.createRoom


    });//Fin N.API.getRooms(function (roomlist)


};//Fin getOrCreateRoom
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var deleteRoomsIfEmpty = function (theRooms, callback) {
    if (theRooms.length === 0){
        callback(true);
        return;
    }
    var theRoomId = theRooms.pop()._id;
    N.API.getUsers(theRoomId, function(userlist) {
        var users = JSON.parse(userlist);
        if (Object.keys(users).length === 0){
            N.API.deleteRoom(theRoomId, function(){
                deleteRoomsIfEmpty(theRooms, callback);
            });
        } else {
            deleteRoomsIfEmpty(theRooms, callback);
        }
    }, function (error, status) {
        console.log('Error getting user list for room ', theRoomId, 'reason: ', error);
        switch (status) {
            case 404:
                deleteRoomsIfEmpty(theRooms, callback);
                break;
            case 503:
                N.API.deleteRoom(theRoomId, function(){
                    deleteRoomsIfEmpty(theRooms, callback);
                });
                break;
        }
    });
};


var cleanExampleRooms = function (callback) {
    console.log('Cleaning basic example rooms');
    N.API.getRooms(function (roomlist) {
        var rooms = JSON.parse(roomlist);
        var roomsToCheck = [];
        for (var room of rooms){
            if (room.data &&
                room.data.basicExampleRoom &&//Comentamos para limpiar todas las rooms excepto basicExampleRoom
                room.name !== defaultRoomName){

                roomsToCheck.push(room);
            }
        }
        deleteRoomsIfEmpty (roomsToCheck, function () {
            callback('done');
        });
    });

};

app.get('/getRooms/', function(req, res) {
    N.API.getRooms(function(rooms) {
//alert('Mensaje desde basic server');//los alert no se pueden mostrar en el servidor
        res.send(rooms);
 var numRooms = JSON.parse(rooms);

console.log('\n* #Room ***** Nombre de rooms creadas ********');
  for(var i in numRooms) {
    console.log('Room ', i, ':  ', numRooms[i].name);
  }
console.log('************************************************');
    });
});

app.get('/getUsers/:room', function(req, res) {
    var room = req.params.room;
    N.API.getUsers(room, function(users) {
        res.send(users);
 var usersList = JSON.parse(users);
console.log('\n************ Usuarios en la room ***************');
  console.log('Esta room tiene ', usersList.length, 'usuario(s)');

  for(var i in usersList) {
    console.log('Usuario ', i, ':', usersList[i].name, 'Con role: ', usersList[i].role);
  }
console.log('\n***********************************************');


    });
});




app.post('/createToken/', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Creating token. Request body: ',req.body);

    let username = req.body.username;
    let role = req.body.role;

    let room = defaultRoomName, type, roomId;

    if (req.body.room && !isNaN(req.body.room)) room = req.body.room;
    if (req.body.type) type = req.body.type;
    if (req.body.roomId) roomId = req.body.roomId;

    let createToken = function (roomId) {
      N.API.createToken(roomId, username, role, function(token) {
          console.log('Token created', token);
          res.send(token);
      }, function(error) {
          console.log('Error creating token', error);
          res.status(401).send('No Erizo Controller found');
      });
    };

    if (roomId) {
      createToken(roomId);
    } else {
      getOrCreateRoom(room, type, createToken);
    }
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'origin, content-type');
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.send(200);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

cleanExampleRooms(function() {
    getOrCreateRoom(defaultRoomName, undefined, function (roomId) {
        defaultRoom = roomId;
        app.listen(3001);
        var server = https.createServer(options, app);
        console.log('BasicExample started XD');
        server.listen(3004);

    });
});
```

Leí en la documentación que para crear un room se necesita un nombre y una función de devolución de llamada (callback function). Pero cuando la ejecuto desde el código no me esta generando la room.

Alguien podria ayudarme a ver en que estoy mal o que me falta para poder crear diferentes usuarios en diferentes rooms?
De antemano muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para crear una sala debes utilizar el API de Nuve, utilizando la llamada `createRoom` como se explica [aquí](http://licode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/server_api/#rooms). Una vez creada obtendrás un identificador de sala que tendrás que utilizar cada vez que quieras conectar a un usuario a dicha sala creando un token de acceso como se explica [aquí](http://licode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/server_api/#tokens). Estas dos llamadas se realizan en el lado servidor. Este token es el que tienes que utilizar en el cliente para [conectarte a una sala](http://licode.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client_api/#room)

Comment: Gracias por responder @Álvaro Alonso, me di cuenta que el código que viene con el proyecto de Licode que clonamos de Github es diferente al código de que se maneja en la documentación de la pagina oficial de Licode y lo comprobé probando el código de la documentación y este me marcaba errores. Se que tal ves sea algo muy sencillo pero si pudieras explicarme con un ejemplo como general las salas desde el cliente en base al código del cliente y del servidor que he puesto te lo agradecería bastante pues he estado intentando pero no lo eh logrado hasta el momento.

Comment: Alonso Ya pude generar diferentes rooms, Ahora quisiera poder limitar el numero de usuarios a dos por sala pero no encuentro donde se modifica ese parámetro. Me podrías guiar para poder lograr mi objetivo?